# How to use HTTP.GET in AngularJS correctly? (Dynamically)

Tags: json, angularjs

I create it has a service, and then pass it to my controller, The problem is that i have it to read a static file only (1.json), and now that i have populated this folder with more than one json, i would like to know, how can I bring them all in, and make this call dynamically.

Service:

```
todoApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $q){
return {
    getEvent: function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/data/phonebook/1'}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

Controller:

```
todoApp.controller('FeederController',
function FeederController($scope, eventData) {
    eventData.getEvent().then(
        function(event){$scope.event = event;},
        function(statusCode) {console.log(statusCode)});
}

);
```

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to parameterize your service call. Once there you can just change your code to handle 1=>N calls rather than one using a loop.

```
todoApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $q){
    return {
    getEvent: function(id){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/data/phonebook/'+id}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config){
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
});
```

and your controller becomes

```
todoApp.controller('FeederController',
   function FeederController($scope, eventData) {
       $scope.events = [];
       for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
       eventData.getEvent(i).then(
           function(event){$scope.events.push(event);},
           function(statusCode) {console.log(statusCode)});
       }
      }
);
```

Comment: After trying your solution, my server dies, I only have 2 entries for now, so i modify the count from 1<2. 

I also added the file extension after ID. After making these changes the server no longer hangs and i am able to see the page, but I can't see the entries.

Perhaps something went wrong on my .HTML or .JSON, If you could please take a look at my gist, and tell me where it went wrong [GIST](https://gist.github.com/misterzik/2a43304a09e424fc7c19) 

Much Respects.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to keep consistent when using .then() vs. .success(). Also, you can use the $http.get() method.

```
todoApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $q){
    return {
       getEvent: function(id){

          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $http.get('/data/phonebook/' + id).then(function(data) {
             deferred.resolve(data);
          }, function (data, status) {
             deferred.reject(status);
          });

          return deferred.promise;
       }
    };
});
```

Then you can get the id of your choice by passing in the id you need.

```
todoApp.controller('FeederController', 
   function FeederController($scope, eventData) {

   $scope.GetEvent = function(id) {
      eventData.getEvent(id).then(function(event){
         $scope.event = event;
      }, function(statusCode) {
       console.log(statusCode);
      });
   };
});
```

Then get the info how ever you want.

Comment: {{event.phone}} won't work, and this is my json file:

`code` {"name": "John Foo",
            "id": 1,
            "phone": "201-555-6666",
            "ext": "123",
            "departs": "Automation"}
`/code`

Comment: @misterzik, how is your json stored? Have you tried ("/data/phonebook/" + id +".json")?

Comment: yes i already did that, i believe there is a problem with how i setup my json please refer to this [Gist]https://gist.github.com/misterzik/2a43304a09e424fc7c19 i posted all my files using the first answer, which is pretty similar to yours. thanks a lot man.

Comment: I see your controller is assigning to a $scope variable of events and your html has event. If events has the info then you need to ng-repeat event in events to get the data.

Comment: thanks buddy, you were right i was messing up by not adding the ng-repeat & calling wrong events. Everything is working sweet now but i've one problem. I decided to go with mikeswright49 solution and using a for loop, but the problem is that it will crash the server if the number of files don't match the count, do you know any way to by pass this error and keep it more dynamically?

https://gist.github.com/misterzik/2a43304a09e424fc7c19

Comment: The easiest way would be to maintain one json file and build a json with nested objects. I don't there is a way to not get an error unless you know exactly how many files there are by keeping a count in a file or use a db to store all your data, but that is a whole different matter.

Comment: Welcome, hope this helped!